# Java Finding Data From ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

This is part of my code and its in two different classes . now i just want to add an option where when you click a find button, you can type the employ ID and display the employ details matching the employ ID from the Array-list.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        viewPanel("card4");
```

---

How can I do it ?

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private empType type;
    private List<Empoyees>objects;
    private int state=0;
    private DefaultListModel df;



public NewJFrame() {
    try {


     initComponents();  
     objects=new ArrayList<Empoyees>();
     objects.add(new Empoyees(123, 25000f,"Mahoshadi"));
     objects.add(new Empoyees(111, 95000f,"Sajani"));
     objects.add(new Empoyees(253, 15000f,"Buwani"));
     objects.add(new Empoyees(687, 66500f,"Thinithi"));


     state=1;
    viewPanel("card2");
      df=new DefaultListModel();
      df.addElement(objects.get(0));
      df.addElement(objects.get(1));
      df.addElement(objects.get(2));
      df.addElement(objects.get(3));  


    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

---

```
public class Empoyees {




private int empId;
private float salary;
private String empName;


public Empoyees(int empId, float salary, String empName) {
    this.empId = empId;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.empName = empName;
}

public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public float getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return   "Name = " + empName + "   , ID = " + empId + "   , Salary = " + salary ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `List`, use a `hashmap`. In that case you can use employee id as key for hashmap. And you can directly retrieve employee details by using hashmap's `get(Object key)` method

```
Map<Integer,Empoyees>employeeCodeEmployeeDetailsMap=new HashMap<Integer,Empoyees>();
```

This will create required map for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a lookup with `List`, you would have to iterate to find the value, something like :

```
for(Employee emp : employees) {
    if(emp.getEmpId() == id) {

    }
}
```

Or else, you could use a `Map` with the `empId` value as the key for easy lookup.

Comment: Good to hear that! You can accept the answer so that others with same issue know that it worked.